# How can I alter the types for material UI alert component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

I am relatively new to Typescript and I have created a snackbar component using React Context and when I try to set the Alert severity, I get this error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Color | undefined'." I do have the type set to a string however, I cannot seem to figure out how to give it a type of Color.
Here is my Alert component:

```
const AppAlert = () => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar open={alertContext.snackbarOpen}>
        <Alert severity={alertContext.snackbarType} variant="filled">
          {alertContext.snackbarMessage}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AppAlert;
```

Here are my Alert prop types:

```
interface AlertProps {
  snackbarOpen: boolean;
  snackbarType: string;
  snackbarMessage: string;
  setAlert: (type: string, message: string) => void;
}
```

I hope I was specific enough as I am still working on understanding TS.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the alert component. See that severity is limited to a few different strings, `'error' | 'info' | 'success' | 'warning'`: https://material-ui.com/api/alert/

Comment: Thanks! I just had to limit the types to those strings and got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The severity of Material-ui alerts can be one of four types `'error' | 'info' | 'success' | 'warning'` according to the documentation [material-ui.com/api/alert](https://material-ui.com/api/alert/). The problem you are having is because the severity property of your `Alert` component has been assigned an `undefined` value from your `alertContext.snackbarType`. To avoid errors if something goes wrong, it would be good practice to set a default severity type as follows:

```js
<Alert severity={alertContext?.snackbarType || 'warning'} variant="filled">
    {alertContext?.snackbarMessage}
</Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and solved it by importing the type from `@material-ui/lab/Alert`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import type { Color } from '@material-ui/lab/Alert'

interface Props{
    severity: Color,
    message: string
}

export const BuildReportAlert = (props: Props) => {

    const {severity, message} = props;

    return (
        <Alert
            variant='outlined'
            severity={severity}
        >
            {message}
        </Alert>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` of React and create a object to store severity and message.

```
const [errorDetail, setErrorDetail] = useState({
    severity: "error",
    message: "This is an info alert — check it out!",
  });
```

and Mui component is below.

```
<Alert severity={errorDetail.severity}>{errorDetail.message}</Alert>
```

it works without any issue and you can modify the severity and message whenever you need.